# How can I dynamically access property of Java object in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

Using GWT I have a Java class:

```
public class Pojo {
  private String name;
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

The above class is shared between the client and server side code.

From the client code I would like to dynamically access the property. That is, I would like to write a method with the following signature:

```
public String getProperty(Object o, String propertyName)
```

Such that the following code would work:

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
pojo.setName("Joe");
getProperty(pojo, "name");    // this should return "Joe"
```

Java reflection is obviously out. And I have tried the following JSNI method:

```
public static native String getProperty(Object o, String name) /*-{
  return o[name];
}-*/;
```

But that does not work.

The [special syntax](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields) for accessing Java objects from JavaScript can't be used either as I want this to be dynamic.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

For completeness, I will also want to be able to set a property dynamically as well.

EDIT: blwy10's answer was a great tip to get me searching using "gwt reflection" instead of with terms like "dynamic property access". This lead me to [gwt-ent](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ent/), which has an very elegant reflection solution. I am going to try this one, as it does not require a separate code generation step.

Comment: The JS code GWT produces is minified and obfuscated by default - so there's a good chance that your `name` property becomes `xz` in one compilation and `werq` in another - no way to know beforehand. You could turn off obfuscation, but that would lead to a significantly bigger JS file.

Comment: wait. why is Java reflection out?

Comment: @Louis: because we are dealing here with Google Web Toolkit (GWT) - it translates Java to JavaScript and only supports [a subset of Java Runtime Library](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but have you tried this?

http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That got me googling using different terms, which got me this: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-ent/
I like this one better, as it does not require a separate code generation step. It is integrated into the GWT compile step.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

http://jpereira.eu/2011/01/30/wheres-my-java-reflection/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GWT's [AutoBean Framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean). Here's a 2-minute-quick-and-dirty example:

```
public interface Person {    
    public String getName();    
    public void setName(String name);    
}


public String getPropertyValue(Person p, String propertyName){
    return AutoBeanUtils.getAllProperties(AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(p)).get(propertyName);
}
```